# Unexpected base 10 logarithm behavior

Tags: python, logarithm

I'm seeing strange behavior with base 10 logarithms in python 2.7.

```
int(log(10**6,10))
```

incorrectly returns 5, while

```
int(log10(10**6))
```

correctly returns 6. What's going on here?

Comment: `log` is not a Python builtin, so it's not clear what your code is doing. You mean `import math; math.log`?

Comment: `math.log(10**6, 10)` yields `5.999999999999999`, and `float`->`int` conversion truncates the decimal portion.

Comment: The question marked as duplicate is not a duplicate. This is ridiculous. @JohnKugelman

Comment: @EdwardD'Souza - It's certainly a duplicate, and not ridiculous at all. `math.log` uses floating-point arithmetic, which can be inaccurate, leading to this sort of error.

Comment: The problem, as pointed out by @JohnKugelman is floating point error. The Python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) incorrectly state that `math.log` returns "the natural logarithm of x". In fact, it doesn't in many cases. It actually returns a floating point approximation of it, which your use of an `int` cast masks.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 If this question was a duplicate, there would be no need for the explanation given in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120918/unexpected-base-10-logarithm-behavior?noredirect=1#comment67512854_40120918). Instead of marking this as a duplicate, and the proceeding to actually answer the question in the comments (which is against the design of SO), the proper thing would be to post that comment as an answer.